# pandas.Series.interpolate() does nothing. Why?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with DatetimeIndex. This is one of columns:

```
>>> y.out_brd
2013-01-01 11:25:00     0.04464286
2013-01-01 11:30:00            NaN
2013-01-01 11:35:00            NaN
2013-01-01 11:40:00    0.005952381
2013-01-01 11:45:00     0.01785714
2013-01-01 11:50:00    0.008928571
Freq: 5T, Name: out_brd, dtype: object
```

When I'm trying to use `interpolate()` on  function I get absolutly nothing changes:

```
>>> y.out_brd.interpolate(method='time')
2013-01-01 11:25:00     0.04464286
2013-01-01 11:30:00            NaN
2013-01-01 11:35:00            NaN
2013-01-01 11:40:00    0.005952381
2013-01-01 11:45:00     0.01785714
2013-01-01 11:50:00    0.008928571
Freq: 5T, Name: out_brd, dtype: object
```

How to make it work?

Update:
the code for generating such a dataframe.

```
time_index = pd.date_range(start=datetime(2013, 1, 1, 3),
                       end=datetime(2013, 1, 2, 2, 59),
                       freq='5T')
grid_columns = [u'in_brd', u'in_alt', u'out_brd', u'out_alt']                           

df = pd.DataFrame(index=time_index, columns=grid_columns)
```

After that I fill cells with some data.

I have dataframe `field_data` with survey data about boarding and alighting on railroad, and `station` variable.
I also have `interval_end` function defined like this:

```
interval_end = lambda index, prec_lvl: index.to_datetime() \
                        + timedelta(minutes=prec_lvl - 1,
                                    seconds=59)
```

The code:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    recs = field_data[(field_data.station_name == station)
                    & (field_data.arrive_time >= index.time())
                    & (field_data.arrive_time <= interval_end(
                                        index, prec_lvl).time())]
    in_recs_num = recs[recs.orientation == u'in'][u'train_number'].count()
    out_recs_num = recs[recs.orientation == u'out'][u'train_number'].count()

    if in_recs_num:
        df.loc[index, u'in_brd'] = recs[
                recs.orientation == u'in'][u'boarding'].sum()    / \
                (in_recs_num * CAR_CAPACITY)
        df.loc[index, u'in_alt'] = recs[
                recs.orientation == u'in'][u'alighting'].sum()   / \
                (in_recs_num * CAR_CAPACITY)
    if out_recs_num:
        df.loc[index, u'out_brd'] = recs[
                recs.orientation == u'out'][u'boarding'].sum()  / \
                (out_recs_num * CAR_CAPACITY)
        df.loc[index, u'out_alt'] = recs[
                recs.orientation == u'out'][u'alighting'].sum() / \
                (out_recs_num * CAR_CAPACITY)
```

Comment: Absolutly the same results I achieve with `linear`, `cubic` and all other methods.

Comment: Can you provide a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/)? Esp. some code to construct your dataframe, that would be nice

Comment: I think interpolate needs regular spaced time series. Looks like you need to resample before.

Comment: Try converting your series to a float dtype.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to convert your `Series` to have a dtype of `float64` instead of your current `object`. Here's an example to illustrate the difference. Note that in general `object` dtype `Series` are of limited use, the most common case being a `Series` containing strings. Other than that they are very slow since they cannot take advantage of any data type information.

```
In [9]: s = Series(randn(6), index=pd.date_range('2013-01-01 11:25:00', freq='5T', periods=6), dtype=object)

In [10]: s.iloc[1:3] = nan

In [11]: s
Out[11]:
2013-01-01 11:25:00   -0.69522
2013-01-01 11:30:00        NaN
2013-01-01 11:35:00        NaN
2013-01-01 11:40:00   -0.70308
2013-01-01 11:45:00    -1.5653
2013-01-01 11:50:00    0.95893
Freq: 5T, dtype: object

In [12]: s.interpolate(method='time')
Out[12]:
2013-01-01 11:25:00   -0.69522
2013-01-01 11:30:00        NaN
2013-01-01 11:35:00        NaN
2013-01-01 11:40:00   -0.70308
2013-01-01 11:45:00    -1.5653
2013-01-01 11:50:00    0.95893
Freq: 5T, dtype: object

In [13]: s.astype(float).interpolate(method='time')
Out[13]:
2013-01-01 11:25:00   -0.6952
2013-01-01 11:30:00   -0.6978
2013-01-01 11:35:00   -0.7005
2013-01-01 11:40:00   -0.7031
2013-01-01 11:45:00   -1.5653
2013-01-01 11:50:00    0.9589
Freq: 5T, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe how trivial this is. I wish there's a warning that pandas cannot interpolate objects ...

Answer (score 2):

I am late but, this solved my problem.
You need to assign the outcome to some variable or itself.

```
y=y.out_brd.interpolate(method='time')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also fix this without changing the name of the data frame with the function "in place":

```
y.out_brd.interpolate(method='time', inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer from Phillip, which I missed the first time and came back to answer it:

You need to have a float series:

```
s.astype(float).interpolate(method='time')
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar issue where `interpolate` was doing nothing.

The problem was that the values that were meant to be interpolated were 0 instead of `np.nan`. You want to make sure that there are `np.nan` values that need to be interpolated. For example:

```
test_pdf["col"] = test_pdf.col.replace(0, np.nan)

test_pdf["interpolated_col"] = test_pdf.col.interpolate(method='linear', direction="forward")

print(test_pdf)
```